# Fronius Gen24 5.0 inverter activates pv point and stops grid feed-in

Tags: photovoltaics

I have a Fronius Symo GEN24 5.0 inverter and I experience a lot of activation of PV point some days and the same time the inverter stops the grid feed in.

(PV point activates when the public grid fails like power outage)

I have tried to discover what can cause the problem, according to the manufacturer, they said if the voltage of grid exceeds the 253V the inverter stops. But the problem is that I did not measure a voltage higher than 253V.

My neighbors did not complain about a feed in or overvoltage problem when I asked them.

My question is what can cause the activation of pv point?

I have connected a monitoring system to the inverter and a Fronius Smart meter. Here are some information from the system.

[image: 2023-08-14 public grid voltage in my smart meter]

[image: 2023-08-14 feed in (KW)]

[image: grid settings in inverter]

[image: grid voltage settings in inverter]